# Workspace name in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, workspaces

I'm testing Ubuntu 22.04.

Is there a way to name my workspaces, for example "Work" and "Home", instead of "1" and "2"?

This is trivial in Xfce, Cinnamon and Kde.

Comment: Did you add the Unity desktop to a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system? or are you using the Ubuntu Unity 22.04 *spin*, as Ubuntu Unity wasn't yet an official *flavor* at 22.04 (this application https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2022-August/002664.html hadn't yet even been made), so Ubuntu Unity 22.04 isn't on-topic here; though later releases are.

Comment: I edited my question. It's not Unity, I think. I'm trying the version of Ubuntu that has no "flavor". I really don't know what is the name of that desktop.

Comment: You'll need to be specific as to what you're using; Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS uses the GNOME desktop, and *modern* GTK4 libraries/toolkits; Xfce & Cinnamon use prior *maintenance mode only* GTK3, KDE uses Qt5...  Unity Desktop was GTK3 and used by to Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop before it was replaced with GNOME; it's an official *flavor* now for 22.10 & newer (meaning 23.10 now given prior releases are EOL).  What you ask is desktop/WM specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since workspaces in Gnome Shell are dynamic by default, there is no big need to name these - they can cease to exist any time. That is probably why it is not made "trivial"  to name work spaces in Gnome Shell: the setting is there, but it is not exposed in the user interface.

You can rename workspaces using the extension  [Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/) by fmuellner.

Naming workspaces probably makes sense only if you use static work spaces, i.e., workspaces that are always there. To configure that, head to "Settings" - "Multitasking". You can change to using a "Fixed number of workspaces", and indicate how much you want. In older versions of Gnome Shell, this setting was exposed in Gnome Tweaks.